# java split () method

Tags: java, split

I've got a string '123' (yes, it's a string in my program). Could anyone explain, when I use this method:

```
String[] str1Array =  str2.split(" ");
```

Why I got `str1Array[0]='123'` rather than `str1Array[0]=1`?

Comment: easy question. flooded answers :P

Comment: everybody wants the cherry on the cake :P

Comment: If none of the answers below work, you probably have a string other than `'123'` in your program. There might be some spaces here and there that you are overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str2` does not contain any spaces, therefore `split` copies the entire contents of `str2` to the first index of `str1Array`.

You would have to do:

```
 String str2 = "1 2 3";
 String[] str1Array =  str2.split(" ");
```

Alternatively, to find every character in str2 you could do:

```
for (char ch : str2.toCharArray()){
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

You could also assign it to the array in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
str2.split("") ;
```

Try this:to split each character in a string .
Output:

```
[, 1, 2, 3]
```

but it  will return an empty first value.

```
str2.split("(?!^)");
```

Output :

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @Leo That will kind of give you almost what you request. It will yield the array  `{"", "1", "2", "3"}`.

Comment: @Leo See my answer I think second one is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

the regular expression that you pass to the split() should have a match in the string so that it will split the string in places where there is a match found in the string. Here you are passing " " which is not found in '123' hence there is no split happening.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's no space in your `String`.
If you want single chars, try `char[] characters = str2.toCharArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Simple...You are trying to split string by space and in your string "123", there is no space

Comment: you know,  String[] str1Array =  str2.split("") ; It doesn't work too(

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `split()` method literally splits the string based on the characters given as a parameter.

We remove the splitting characters and form a new String every time we find the splitting characters.

```
String[] strs =  "123".split(" ");
```

The String `"123"` does not have the character `" "` (space) and therefore cannot be split apart. So returned is just a single item in the array - `{ "123" }`.

Answer (score 1):

To do the "Split" you must use a delimiter, in this case insert a "," between each number

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] list = "123456".replaceAll("(\\d)", ",$1").substring(1)
            .split(",");
    for (String string : list) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

String str = "123";
String res = str.split("");

will return the following result:

1,2,3