# What does the regular expression, /(?!^)/g mean?

Tags: javascript, regex

What does the regular expression, `/(?!^)/g` mean?

I can see that from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) `x(?!y)`: Matches `x` only if `x` is not followed by `y`.

That explains, if `?!` is used before any set of characters, it checks for the *not followed by* condition.

But we have, `?!^`. So, if we try to say it in words, it would probably mean *not followed by negate*. That really does not make me guess a probable statement for it. I mean *negate of what*?

I'm still guessing and could not reach a fruitful conclusion.

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: *"That explains, if `?!` is used before any set of characters"* -- it is **not** `?!`. It is `(?!y)` where `y` is a `regex`. The parentheses are part of the notation. Without them, `?!` does not have any special meaning (apart from `?` marking the piece it follows as being optional).

Comment: *"it would probably mean not followed by negate."* -- `^` means *"negate"* only when it is the first character of a character set (`[^...]`). Otherwise it means beginning of string (or beginning of line).

Comment: *"I'm still guessing"* -- stop guessing, start reading the documentation. The JavaScript documentation is scarce, indeed. I recommend you the [PHP documentation of regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php). It is more detailed.

Comment: Sites such as regex101.com have a built-in explanation component that parses and explains the pattern you specify.

Comment: @Fred They have a breakdown but flow of matching couldn't be explained well by looking at some lines explaining a token.

Comment: I suggest you to use [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to learn about regex

Comment: This shows the expression matches infinitely

Answer (score 2):

Circumflex `^` only implies negation in a character class `[^...]` (when comes as first character in class). Outside of it it means start of input string or line. A negative lookahead that contains `^` only, means match shouldn't be found at start of input string or line.

See it [in action](https://regex101.com/r/vfEiNF/1)

Comment: You assume that `/`and `/g`is not part of the pattern? I assume it's part of the pattern and I fail to see what the difference is between `//g` and `/(?!^)/g`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I assume them as part of pattern but delimiters are constant and we don't need flags here to explain the logic. So I could skip them easily. The difference is `//g` matches positions and this `/(?!^)/g` does the same with one match less.

Comment: I don't think it does?! Using Regexbuddy's Debugging facility, `/(?!^)/g` needs 5 steps where `//g` only takes 3 steps to find a match.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers RegexBuddy doesn't accept delimiters and flags as in JS. You don't put `/(?!^)/g` but `(?!^)`.

Comment: tx, that was what tripped me up. The regex is `(?!^)`. The rest is javascript fluff.

Answer (score 2):

It returns

- all matches... (`/g`, global flag)
- ...which are not followed by... (`x?!y`, negative lookahead where `x` is the empty string)
- ...the position at the start of the string (`^`)

That is, any position between two characters except for the position at the start of the string, as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/vfEiNF/2).

This regex is useful, thus, for detecting empty strings (after all, applying the regex to an empty string will return no matches). Empty strings may be the result of [splitting strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25071159/what-is-the-meaning-of), and you probably don't want to do anything with them.